What is the correct notation for geometric sequence?
I'm trying to write a formula that generalizes the following set of equations:
 $y_1=\sqrt{50-1}$ 
 $y_2=\sqrt{50-2}+y_1$ 
 $y_3=\sqrt{50-3}+y_2$ 
 $y_4=\sqrt{50-4}+y_3$ 
 ... 
I'm not very familiar with geometric sequences, but my best attempt is:
 $f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^x \sqrt{50-i}$

Your formula is correct, but this is not a geometric sequence.
